# Export from mvc into OneDrive

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, export, office365, onedrive

I want to implement a feature which allows me to export files(eg.excel file) from an MVC app into OneDrive.

What would be the best method of implementing such a feature?
Are there any best practices regarding such implementations

Comment: @Rabban Yes that is correct. I understand this concept.
Just trying to find out if there are best practices regarding exporting files to one drive.